# What is an individual instance of a data type called?

Tags: c#, computer-science, abstract-data-type

This is just out of my own curiosity; I was looking for the right word while asking a question in a discussion today. I don't have a computer science background.

Is there a proper word for any given instance of a *partition* of a particular data type?

Is it simply value? Index? Say I'm talking about a byte in C#, which can take an unsigned integer primitive value of 0 to 255. Conceptually, I am thinking that there are 256 "boxes" that are filled by these "values," and I am looking for the word that refers to the "box," if there is one.

Comment: "valid value"?  "value within a valid range"?  Since a `byte` can only be one of those values, then any one of those values would simply be a `byte` I suppose.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot "divide" a type.

Comment: "State" I guess.  As in, the memory in the byte can have 256 states.

Comment: @dtanders that's just a value right?

Comment: @Alex when you're talking about a type like a byte they're basically the same, but an object with two boolean members has four states, for example.

Comment: It's actually probably better to think of there being 8 boxes, each being a binary bit, so each bit has two states (1 and 0). Since a byte contains 8 bits, a byte can have 2^8 = 256 states. The very most fundamental unit of value is the bit, however, the byte is the smallest addressable unit of memory and the base of memory multiples (KB, MB, GB, etc.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its an etimology question, and not a programming problem.

Comment: @Servy "What is this programming-related concept called" seems pretty on-topic unless there's another community about CS theory.  There are too many to keep track of, so there might be :)

Comment: @dtanders There doesn't need to be another SE site about a topic for that topic to be off topic on SO.  SO is for programming problems.  This isn't a programming problem.

Comment: @Servy I'd say this question is about tools commonly used by programmers (jargon being a tool) and is "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"

Comment: @dtanders But it's not about a tool used by programmers.  It's a language question.

Comment: @Servy jargon is a tool - you just use it so often you forget you use it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called state.  Talking about every possible state you're looking for the term [state space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_space).

An 8-bit byte has 256 possible states because there are two possible states per bit so you have 2^8 states.  A C-style struct with two boolean members can have four states or 2^2.  Two bytes and you're looking at 256^256 states.  State space gets big fast.

Answer (score 3):

It's simply '*value*'.

A location in memory -- i.e. what a variable in a program refers to -- can hold a range of values.

As @Miller pointed out, you might also be looking for '*variable*': a label that refers to a particular location in memory where a value is being held.

In source code, you'll often express particular values as '*literals*'.  In this example, 200 is an *integer literal*.

`int x = 200;`

In this example, "a" is a *character literal*.

`char a = 'a';`

Comment: Technically, I would call it simply a 'variable'. But that may be confusing if you think of algebraic variable.

Comment: @Miller excellent point.  That fits well with the "boxes" imagery.

Answer (score 3):

In C#, if you have a variable of type byte, then the variable's value is initialized (or later assigned) a "value". But there are not 256 "boxes" in a byte, rather there are 8 bits. The value of the byte is equal to the sum of the value of the 8 bits. For instance, setting byte x = 13, would be stored as 8 bits with the binary values 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to say simply variable.
In execution of program the value of an instance may change. Variable is a location which can hold a value defined by the type. Type also allocate memory  to each variable (an instance of the primitive type). Its value or state can be changed during program execution.

```
int i=0;
while (i<100)
{
  i=i+1;
}
```

i is an integer data type and it can hold any number that is allowed by integer type.

see more https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science)